# how to make separate caching pages base on cookie value?

Tags: php, nginx, varnish, varnish-vcl

I Would like to serve adaptive images sizes base on the user screen resolution.

I came across this great solution [Adaptive Images](http://adaptive-images.com/), but this solution won't work properly with varnish.

because for example - if client a with mobile will request image then the image will be stored in varnish cache as small image for mobiles. and this image will be served later on to desktop users as well.

I think that if i'll find a way to separate the caching pages base on cookie value (part of the [adaptive images](http://adaptive-images.com/) script) - then each image will be kept base on the user screen width.

therefore, if i'm not wrong then the bad situation that i've described above will be solved.

Can you please help me create the right vcl code for this.
1. The separation should be applied to images only (jpg,gif,png).
2. and it should separate each cache based on the value of cookie_a

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you have to do is change the vcl_hash method where varnish stores data to use the cookie, only when the url is an image (jpg, gif, png).
For the sake of simplicity, let's assume Varnish stores the image in the key "image.jpg", what you have to do is to tell Varnish that the key is 'image-[size].jpg" where [size] can be the cookie, the image size or both.
To solve the 'only for images' issue you have to do something like

```
if (req.url ~ '(jpg|gif|png)') {
    // Change the hash here
}
```

With that in mind, [here](http://varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleCachingLoggedInUsers) you can find a good example of how to do it.
Other useful sites:

- [vcl_hash](http://book.varnish-software.com/3.0/VCL_functions.html#vcl-vcl-hash) (varnish 3)
- [Basic hashing](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-hashing.html)